# Parameterised query expects a parameter (Not accepting Null string)

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters

I am just carrying out a query, and have started using parameters. And all was going great, until a null string is passed. It worked fine before, using `"name = " + Name` Where name may or maynot be null.

Is there as simple way around this?

Also on the topic, I havent tried it yet, but can I identify parameters by anything other than numbers. It is a potential area to go wrong, having 14 number parameters with no identification to which is which, except hoping they are in the correct order. (What if i come to add another in)

Error message : `The parameterized query '(@0 nvarchar(5),@1 nvarchar(4),@2 nvarchar(4000),@3 nvarchar(400' expects the parameter '@2', which was not supplied.`

The Parameterised query:

```
            db.Execute("Update User SET Name = @0 , Address1 = @1 , Address2 = @2 , Address3 = @3, Address4 = @4 , Postcode = @5 , Title = @6, " +
                        " Surname = @7 , Forename = @8 , Tel = @9, Fax = @10 , Mobile = @11 , Email = @12  WHERE UserNo = @13",
                        Name, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Postcode, Title, Surname, Forename, Tel, Fax, Mobile, Email, UserNo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Execute("Update User SET Name = @0 , Address1 = @1 , Address2 = @2 , Address3 = @3, Address4 = @4 , Postcode = @5 , Title = @6, " +
                        " Surname = @7 , Forename = @8 , Tel = @9, Fax = @10 , Mobile = @11 , Email = @12  WHERE UserNo = @13",
                        (Name==null)?"":Name, (Address1==null)?"":Address1, ...);
```

Comment: Okay, so thats similar to doing `Name ?? ""` ? What does the :Name bit do? I was hoping not to do this to every nullable parameter.

Comment: `condition ? first_expression : second_expression;` its [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx). In this case yes its same as `Name ?? ""`